# Cannot access Compiz Config

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I was going through one article [here](http://techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_the_Ubuntu_11.04_Unity_Launcher_and_Workspaces) and the topic was "Changing the Size and Appearance of the Unity Launcher" which required to open up CompizConfig from System Settings --> Desktop. I could find System Settings and could reach to control panel but cannot locate either Desktop or CompizConfig. When i go to Software center and search for compizconfig, it says that it is already installed.But when i search it from the list of installed applications, i couldn't find it.??

Comment: Try running it from the Terminal:
`ccsm` Does it pop up?

Comment: what does it say when you open terminal and type there 

ccsm

Answer (score 4):

CCSM (compizconfig-settings-manager) is not installed by default. To install it go to the Software Center or click on the link below:

[compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

Then you can open it by typing `ccsm` in the Dash or run it from *System Settings*

> **Warning:** ccsm can lead to unwanted effects that may be hard to overcome and may leave you without a desktop (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/3940) for more background information).

You may have installed [simple-ccsm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/simple-ccsm) instead.

Comment: He clearly mentions that Ubuntu Software Center says it's installed.

Comment: @Oxwivi: CompizConfig(simple-ccsm) != CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm)

Comment: Ah, that you should have mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing Compiz Config Settings Manager (or ccsm) by pressing Alt+F2 and typing `ccsm`. The Unity settings are in there, just type "unity" into the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

In the Applications lens (at the launcher), on the extreme right of the search bar, you will see "All Applications" written along with an arrow. Click n it and choose "System". You should be able to see CompizConfig Settings Manager there.